# CoroutineScope by MainScope() launch not executing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am trying to use the `MainScope()` scope. I thought this allowed me to just call `launch` whenever I need a new coroutine with the option of specifying which Dispatcher I want it to run on if I don't want it on Dispatchers.Main. However some of my calls to `launch` don't execute at all.

- This code first retrieves a setting db value from Room.
- When the preference switch is clicked, it performs a network request to write a new setting on the server.
- If the response is successful, I want to update the local db value in Room. The second launch within the observed response is never executed. Without a call to launch, I am (correctly) told by Room not to write on the main thread.

  ```
  class PrefsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Injectable, CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var settings: BranchSettingsRepository

  @Inject
  lateinit var preferencesHelper: PreferencesHelper

  var groupID = 0
  var branchID = 0

  override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
      setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      groupID = preferencesHelper.merchantGroupID.toInt()
      branchID = preferencesHelper.merchantBranchID.toInt()

      createAutoAcceptSetting(view)
  }

  private fun createAutoAcceptSetting(root: View) {
      launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

          val setting = settings.getSettingByName(preferencesHelper.merchantBranchID, AUTO_ACCEPT)

          if (setting != null) {
              val preference = findPreference<SwitchPreferenceCompat>(AUTO_ACCEPT)
              preference?.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { pref, newValue ->

                  var valueAsIntString = "0"
                  if (newValue as Boolean) {
                      valueAsIntString = "1"
                  }
                  updateSetting(groupID, branchID, setting.id, valueAsIntString)
                          .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
                              response?.let {
                                  if (it.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                                      Timber.i("New setting updated (old value was: $setting)")
                                      Timber.i("launching db write with value: $valueAsIntString")

                                      launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                                          //This code is never executed
                                          setting.value = valueAsIntString
                                          Timber.i("writing new setting: $setting")
                                          settings.insertSetting(setting)
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          })
                  true
              }
          }
      }
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy()
      cancel()
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: It's no longer necessary to create your own MainScope and cancel it in `destroy()`, because there is the `lifecycleScope` extension property provided by KTX. Are those logs right above the never-executed launch happening?

Comment: Ok thank you yes I see that now, I find this stuff changes a lot :) Yes the logs before the second launch to print and then nothing, it's like the inner launch doesn't exist. I will try with the lifecycleScope and see if it behaves.